# Нужен адаптивный кривой блок (svg, css) ie9

Tags: css3, вёрстка, svg, адаптивная-верстка, кроссбраузерность

Нужен вон такой адаптивный блок, в ие9-11 width:100% для svg не работает.

***Подскажите способ как сделать такое адаптивно?*** спасибо!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может before & after & skew? создать два псевдоэлемента повернуть их? задать ширину в %, надо попробовать!

Comment: А before & after тут причём?

Comment: Тупанул, думал два блока сверху и снизу прикрутить кривых, но как показывает пример ниже можно один блок так трансформировать.

Comment: Если два, то можно и rotate использовать :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью `transform`:

```css
div {
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  display:block;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg) skewX(-5deg) skewY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg) skewX(-5deg) skewY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg) skewX(-5deg) skewY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg) skewX(-5deg) skewY(0deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg) skewX(-5deg) skewY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Отступы сверху и снизу можно добить медиа запросами в зависимости от того, что там у вас

Answer (score 3):

Еще как вариант

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 100px;  
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}
div:before{
    bottom: 100%;     
    border-width: 0 0 50px 100vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
}
div:after{
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 50px 100vw 0 0;
    border-color: green transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: интересный пример