# Div наклонные внутренние и внешние стороны

Tags: css, вёрстка, html

Текст и картинка будут меняться.

У div наклонен низ и внутри полупрозрачная тень.

Это возможно сделать только с помощью HTML и CSS, без JS? Как это сделать?

Я пробовал `clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);`
Вообще не работает. Вставлял полностью пример с другого сайта и он тоже у меня не сработал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проще у нижнего блока сделать фон градиентом

Comment: можно без проблем сделать clip-pah-ОМ, но учти, что в IE и  EDGE  работать  не будет

Comment: Air Да мне хоть как нибудь сделать) Сейчас у меня вообще не как не получается.

Comment: Я не знаток, а только учусь, но мне кажется, что для решения этого вопроса подойдет свойство transform: skew().

Comment: смотри, вот тебе clip-pah-ОМ

Comment: [Фигурный элемент в вёрстке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692129/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5/692182#692182)

Comment: [Стилизация блоков, как создать шестиугольный блок?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/699977/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA/700235#700235)

Comment: [Нужен адаптивный кривой блок (svg, css) ie9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641297/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-svg-css-ie9/641299#641299)

Comment: вы хотя бы гуглите, перед тем как вопрос задавать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учтите clip-path в IE и EDGE работать не будет

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#bg {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://clapsjoker.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/manzarawindowstemacom.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 80%, 100% 0);
}

#shd {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55%;
  background: #00000095;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 45%, 0 100%, 100% 88%, 100% 0);
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 153px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34%;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="bg">
    <div id="shd"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere atque dicta et consequuntur porro perspiciatis, molestias, itaque rerum magnam iste qui recusandae tenetur culpa molestiae quidem labore assumenda aspernatur, accusantium?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: вид и размеры можешь сам изменить...

Comment: Вставил ваш код полностью и почему то не работает. У меня не цепляет картинку вашу. Текст появился, а картинка нет. Я пользуюсь Sass перекомпилировал ваш код вот скрин.
http://www.imgzilla.ru/image.uploads/2017-11-03/original-f80191bdf5c3bdc4e984350c75711e2b.png

Comment: а clip-path сработал? картинку свою вставь?

Comment: А ссылку вашу оставить нельзя?
Я пытался вставить свою картинку тоже не работает. 
Я заметил если вставляю картинку в html через img то все работает, а если через css (Sass) background: url, background-image: url то не чего не работает.
Пути пытался все возможные. Даже просто скинул картинку в папку где находиться файл Sass(сss) и все равно не погрузилось.
Бред какой то.

Comment: путь, возьми в ковычки

Comment: Брал в ковырни и сcылку и свои картинки.
Я вспомнил что до этого верстал сайт и у меня " background-image: url"
срабатывало только к Header, но не к div.
Можно как нибудь без этой команды?

Comment: почитай https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021306/background-images-path-in-sass-and-compass

Comment: можешь показать весь свой sass?

Comment: То что в файле написано? Вот: http://www.imgzilla.ru/image.uploads/2017-11-03/original-cad32ad880d19e55a89fe11bf1d7c72f.png
или как?

Comment: чем sass компилируешь ?

Comment: Gulp. Ошибки смотрел, нету.

Comment: Все разобрался. У меня был косяк с подключением сss.
Спасибо за код)

Comment: расскажи, в чем именно косяк?

Answer (score 2):

```css
#block:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 120px;
  border-top: 45px solid #fff;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 456px solid transparent;
}

#block {
  width: 456px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://imagecdn2.panjo.com/images/facebook/cydq1vb6skdF.JPG) center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#block:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 35px solid #fff;
  border-left: 456px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе) Ну ты сделал наклон только внешней стороны. А там видишь на картинки еще внутри есть полупрозрачная тень она тоже наклонена.

Comment: @aksiman как то так...

Comment: Полностью вставил ваш код и не работает у меня почему то.
[ссылка] (http://www.imgzilla.ru/image.uploads/2017-11-03/original-8eedd1f552d8ac92cc7ded5bed444ec8.png)
Я пользуюсь SASS перекомпилировал ваш код.

Comment: @aksiman  https://jsfiddle.net/Lwwrukp7/

Comment: @aksiman https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LONEKQ

Comment: У меня походу проблема именно с командой "background: url"
Она у меня не применяется к div почему то. Только к Header, body и footer.

Comment: Все разобрался. У меня был косяк с подключением сss.
Спасибо за код)